# How to get division Id through javascript and send through ajax to php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hey I am working on a project and notifications field. All is going well, but I faced a problem, I want to send the notification ID through ajax to the php file to make it as read.

i.e I made notifications to appear as in divisions with their own id

```
<div id=‘<?php echo $n_id ; ?>’class=‘notifications’>
<div class=“head”>
Hi Users Party Is On</div>
</div>
```

And I want to add onclick attribute so that when a user clicks that,javascript function is triggered and through ajax the id is sent to php file and code runs and the notification will be marked read.

```
<div id=‘<?php echo $id; ?>’ onclick=‘update(this.id)’ class=‘notifications’>
<div class=‘head’>Hi Users Party Is On?</div>
</div>
```

And my ajax code is

```
function update(str) {
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("mpk").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",”update.php?value="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Where is your ajax code?

Comment: `id=‘<?php echo $n_id ; ?>’` <- those are the wrong type of quotes (those are ticks). Use ordinary `'` (single quotes).

Comment: Yo I know that those are ticks but my mobile keyboard supports only those type of ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` i.e : current div clicked reference in your function and then get id of that div using `variable.id`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
function update(str) {
var ids = str.id; 
console.log(ids)
  //send "ids"  ajax call
}
```

```html
<div id="1" onclick="update(this)" class="notifications">
<div class="head">Hi Users Party Is On?</div>
</div>
<div id="2" onclick="update(this)" class="notifications">
<div class="head">Hi Users Party Is On?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: great mam !!!! one question is that how to create `run code snipet button` by posting answer?.

Comment: click `ctrl+m` then  code snippet window will get open put html js etc code there and  save it